# Identify process

Tags: process, osx, top, background-process

Every couple of minutes my Mac OSX machine starts running a process that consumes 10% of the CPU. It runs for a couple of seconds and then stops. I can see the process coming up in 'Top', but the name of the process is generic (i.e., 'bash'). What can I do to further pinpoint the exact command/script that is being run?

Comment: `sudo lsof -p the-pid-of-that-process`. `ps -fjlp the-pid-of-that-process` and identify its parent (with the same command on the PPID)